# is there a way to determine udisks default mount path?

Tags: python, bash, udisks

It can be `/media/` or `/media/$USER` or `/run/media/$USER` depends on distro or customization. Is there a unified way to get its value programmatically regardless distros?

Comment: Maybe try in [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [Super User](https://superuser.com/), since there is nothing about programming in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/610747/change-default-mount-point-for-udisks), where they reference a passage from the man page for [udisks](/questions/tagged/udisks):

> UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED : If set to 1, the filesystem on the device
> will be mounted in a shared directory (e.g. /media/VolumeName) instead
> of a private directory (e.g./run/media/$USER/VolumeName) when the
> Filesystem.Mount() method is handled.

Comment: what you mentioned it is compiling time setting. And it can be 3 different paths instead of just 2. I doubt this can help. I simply just want a way to determine the distro's setting instead of manually put a dictionary

Comment: You might want to check out  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=259493